# A little problem about convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If we know that $\sum a_n$ converges, could we derive that $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{n}$ also converges? (Suppose we don't have $a_n \ge 0$) If not, please give an example~

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Use [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test). Note that if $\sum a_n$ converges then its partial sums are bounded and moroever the sequence $1/n$ is positive and decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) (in the wikipedia article take $b_n=a_n$ and $a_n=1/n$).